# Why are the visibility of a ImageView duplicated When I click an item of recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I click on a item of the recyclerView, others item change his visibility too.
I have an recyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/apps_installed_list"
    android:name="com.campanon.bipbip.activities.ListAppsActivity"
    android:layout_width="380dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_cancel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInstalledApps"
    tools:listitem="@layout/app_installed_item_list">
```

Row item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/app_name"
    android:layout_width="272dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/app_package"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/app_icon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/app_package"
    android:layout_width="272dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_name" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/selected_app"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I click on an item, the last ImageView (selected_app) change his visibility. I don't know why other item in the list change the visibility too with only 1 click.

This is the list on the app:

[image: Screenshot]

In the adapter I have implemented the click with the holder.view:

```
public class ListAppsInstalledAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAppsInstalledAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
private PackageManager packageManager;
private Context context;
CustomItemClickListener listener;
private static List<ApplicationInfo> appsSelected;


public static List<ApplicationInfo> getAppsSelected() {
    return appsSelected;
}

public ListAppsInstalledAdapter(Context context, List<ApplicationInfo> appsList, CustomItemClickListener listener) {
    this.appsList = appsList;
    this.context = context;
    this.packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    this.listener = listener;
    appsSelected = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.app_installed_item_list, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = appsList.get(position);

    holder.appName.setText(applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
    holder.packageName.setText(applicationInfo.packageName);
    holder.iconview.setImageDrawable(applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holder.selectedApp.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                holder.selectedApp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                appsSelected.add(applicationInfo);
            } else {
                holder.selectedApp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                appsSelected.remove(applicationInfo);
            }
            listener.onItemClick(view, position);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return appsList.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final TextView appName;
    public final TextView packageName;
    public ImageView iconview;
    public ImageView selectedApp;
    public final View mView;



    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_package);
        iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
        selectedApp = (ImageView) 
view.findViewById(R.id.selected_app);

    }


}


}
```

I do not know what to do :(

Comment: could you share your complete adapter?

Comment: yes! I edited the post! :)

Comment: Where are you implementing this? listener.onItemClick(view, position);

Comment: I have an interface: public interface CustomItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position);
} and impements in the activity but I don't use now for nothing.

Comment: I understood, i mean, you implement the interface somewhere. What you're doing in the implementation of this method?

Comment: In my Activity I have this implementations:   adapter = new ListAppsInstalledAdapter(this, listApplicationInfo, new CustomItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                Log.i("app", " clicked position: " + position);
                ApplicationInfo app = listApplicationInfo.get(position);
                Log.i("Name", " APP: " + app.packageName);
              //  appsSelected.add(app);
               // appsSelectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

Comment: That's a mistake, I deleted the interface. Visibility only change in the adapter.

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque sorry removed comment. not visible code properly that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListAppsInstalledAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAppsInstalledAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    private Context context;
    CustomItemClickListener listener;
    private static List<ApplicationInfo> appsSelected;
    private List<Integer> selectedPos = new ArrayList<>();


    public static List<ApplicationInfo> getAppsSelected() {
        return appsSelected;
    }

    public ListAppsInstalledAdapter(Context context, List<ApplicationInfo> appsList, CustomItemClickListener listener) {
        this.appsList = appsList;
        this.context = context;
        this.packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        this.listener = listener;
        appsSelected = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.app_installed_item_list, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = appsList.get(position);

        holder.appName.setText(applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager));
        holder.packageName.setText(applicationInfo.packageName);
        holder.iconview.setImageDrawable(applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager));

        if(selectedPos.contains(position)){
            holder.selectedApp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else {
            holder.selectedApp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return appsList.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public final TextView appName;
        public final TextView packageName;
        public ImageView iconview;
        public ImageView selectedApp;
        public final View mView;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer pos = getAdapterPosition();
            if(selectedPos.contains(pos)){
                selectedPos.remove(pos);
            }else{
                selectedPos.add(pos);
            }
            listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());

        }

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
            packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_package);
            iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
            selectedApp = (ImageView)
                    view.findViewById(R.id.selected_app);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


    }


}
```

In your interface implementation call `notifyDatasetChanged()` in your adapter to reload the recyclerview with the selected position.

Comment: Thank you! I have done that but it doesn't work. It does not enter the onClick method implemented in the ViewHolder.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to associate the listener with the view. Add view.setOnClickListener(this) inside the view holder constructor; Please check the edit

Comment: Yes! Now It works! I had to change the position of selectedPos = getAdapterPosition() on top of listener. Now I have another issue, if I click on an item that is selected, It don't change it's visibility to invisible.

Comment: It works but now I only can select 1 option, I can't select multiple options.

Comment: all sorry, I planned it all thinking you'd want to select just one option :/. Just a second, I'll change my answer

Comment: checkt it out, I've replaced the selectedPos variable with a list

Comment: Now Yes!! It works!!! Thank you! I have edited your answer with some mistakes fixed.